# Streaming App with 2 topologies, do I need multiple groupIds?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'd like to build a streaming app with 2 topologies; combined to simplify deployment and maintenance, etc.

Both topologies will refer to a separate GlobalKTable created from the same topic. Will I need multiple groupIDs to avoid interference between topologies when referencing their associated GKTable? e.g. are separate offsets needed?

Comment: How are you creating the topologies? Do both share the same `application.id` config?

Comment: Is the output topic of both the topologies same?

Comment: @OneCricketeer. I would like to use a separate application.id for each topology. Is there any problem doing this?

Comment: @deadzg_devil : output topics are different per topology

Comment: That should be fine... You should be able to create multiple topologies in the same deployable application. They just have different config properties. I'm not sure how you'd manage the metrics or exception-handling for both, though.